# Is a Complex Inner Product defined to be anti-linear (conjugate linear) to both arguments corrrect?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, inner-products

I know that we can have complex inner products defined such as

- Conjugate linear to first argument: `SUM(conj(lhsElement), rhsElement)`
- Conjugate linear to second argument: `SUM(lhsElement, conj(rhsElement))`

Can we have a complex inner product defined to be conjugate linear to both arguments, such as
`SUM(conj(lhsElement), conj(rhsElement))`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community all I’m asking is whether the latest definition of the inner complex product can be said to be correct. The first two are, but I don’t know whether the third one is as well

Comment: Complex inner products by definition are designed to capture and generalize the norms of euclidean spaces to general infinite dimensional spaces (like Hilbert spaces), i.e the inner product of an element with itself should be a non-negative number. For this reason an inner product can be conjugate linear in only one argument. For instance $||ax||^2=\left<ax,ax\right>=\overline{a^2}||x||^2$ would not make sense

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, otherwise your inner product won't be positive definite. Indeed, let $\langle\,\cdot\,,\cdot\,\rangle : V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a hermitian "bi-anti-linear" form. Then, taking a vector $v \in V$ such that $\langle v,v \rangle > 0$, then $\langle iv,iv \rangle = -\langle v,v \rangle < 0$, and *vice versa*.